# c# wrong number of indices inside [] expected 2

Tags: c#

I am doing PrimSparse algorithm and it says I need two indices in my for loop

```
private Node z;
adj = new int[V + 1, V + 1];
Node t;

for (t = adj[v]; t != z; t = t.next)
{
    if (t.wgt < dist[u])
    {
        //puts the distance between the two vertex as the current data
        dist[v] = t.wgt;
        parent[u] = v;

        //making sure when the vertex is == 0 then insert the vertex
        if (hPos[u] == 0)
        {
            h.insert(t.vert);
        }
        else
        {
            //or otherwise just move up the position of the vertex
            h.siftUp(hPos[t.vert]);
        }
    }
}
```

the very first line is giving me the CS0022 error, absolutely no idea why, when i put in a second it says "cannot convert int to Graph.node"

any ideas?

Comment: What are the types of 't', 'z', 'adj', and 't.next'?

Comment: `t` and `z` are nodes, yet you set `t = adj[v]`, when `adj` is an int array. Not sure what you want, but a Node != Int[].

Comment: what do you understand from that error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is relatively straightforward:

CS0022 is "Wrong number of indices inside []"

adj is declared as a 2D array of ints, so you will need to supply two indices when you dereference it, not one.  This is just how arrays work.

You seem to have correctly diagnosed that issue - so onto the 2nd:

Dereferencing an adj gives you an int.  You're then trying to assign an int to t, which has a type of "node"  There's no conversion defined between "int" and "node", thus the 2nd error message.  You can read it as straight English, "Cannot convert an int to a node" - but you have to make one more logical step.  Why is a conversion from int to node necessary?  Because you're trying to do assignment.  Maybe a more verbose error message would be "Cannot assign an int to a variable of type Node because there is no conversion specified"

**Some Lurking issues:**

Comparing T and Z should be no problem.  They're both Nodes.  You may need to provide your own equality operator though.  By default, != is going to do a reference compare.  You may or may not want to compare references.

Finally, assuming the type of t.next is also a node, the last part of your for loop should be OK too.

Comment: Exactly. This is all about just looking at the types and the error messages. I'm not really sure that the error messages if read properly couldn't have said all of this...

Comment: Excellent explanation, thanks! Is it possible to put t = adj[v] through some sort of conversion or will I need to find a different way?

Comment: @Chris Agreed - although there is one minor logical leap that you have to make from "Can't convert X to Y" to "Can't assign an X to a Y because I can't do the conversion"

Comment: @user3512805 You could make adj into a 2D array of nodes instead of a 2D array of ints.  I'm not really clear on what the data in adj represents so it's hard to offer good advice here.  You could also have an implicit or explicit conversion, but I doubt that's the right tool for this job.  Implicit conversions should only happen when you can safely round-trip.  I also doubt that there's enough info for an explicit conversion.  Does an "int" really contain enough information to be converted to a "node"?  I doubt it.

Comment: That pastebin link claims to have had its contents removed... If you want more help though may be worth making it a further question rather than asking more in comments.